# Do any Scriptures mention the Shaivite Ritual of Linga-Dharana?

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas, shaivism, shiva-lingam

Do any Vedas, Puranas or Agamas mention the Shaivite ritual of Linga-Dharana?

Answer (score 0):

I could find an untraceable reference to the Kāmikāgama and a further reference to the Vātulāgama. This was mentioned in the book ["The Descent of Scripture"](https://escholarship.mcgill.ca/concern/theses/n583z0711) (p. 163).

> On the distinctly Vīraśaiva practice of carrying a liṅga on one’s person (*liṅgadhāraṇa*), one verse in the Śrīkarabhāṣya attributed to the Kāmika, not found in the modern text, is notable for its reference to the practice.
>
> Thus in the Kāmika [it is said,] “**The holding of a liṅga in [one’s] hand (*pāṇiliṅgadhṛtiḥ*) is [to be] practiced (*samīritā*) at all times with the mantra of the Veda personified, ‘This hand of mine is the Lord’**.”
>
> The reference is terse, yet we find no references to holding a liṅga in one’s hand in the modern Kāmika. **In the Śrīkarabhāṣya, the verse is preceded by a citation from the Vātula, which also refers to the practice of holding a liṅga in one’s hand.** Notably, in the verse quoted above, there is also the injunction to recite a mantra from the Ṛgveda (*ayaṃ me hasto bhagavān*), which is not found in the modern Kāmika either. Assuming Śrīpati was faithfully citing the Kāmika as he knew it (and we have no reason to assume otherwise) we may surmise that this was a Vīraśaiva recension of the Kāmika.

The Śrīkarabhāṣya does not mention the word liṅgadhāraṇa directly though.

> Śrīkarabhāṣya (1977 Ed.), 17.
>
> tathā kāmike –
> ayaṃ me hasto bhagavān iti mantreṇa sarvadā |
> pāṇiliṅgadhṛtir vedapuruṣasya samīritā || 
> ...
> etad evavātūle [sic] śrūyate – dhārayed yas tu hastena liṅgākāraṃ śivaṃ sadā |
> tasya hastasthitaṃ viddhi matpadaṃ sampadāṃ padam ||
>
> “This is stated in the Vātula – ‘But whoever should hold the eternally auspicious ( śivaṃ sadā ) form of the liṅga with their hand, know that established in that person’s hand is my abode ( matpadaṃ ), an abode of riches’.”

Regarding the Vātulāgama, the ["History of Indian Philosophy Volume 5"](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/a-history-of-indian-philosophy-volume-5/d/doc210063.html) says:

> The Vātula-tantra seems to have two editions (in manuscript), and in one of them the ṣaṭ-sthala doctrine is mentioned in the form of an appendix, which shows that this introduction was of the nature of an apocrypha. **The doctrine of liṅga-dhāraṇa in the manner in which it is done by the Liṅgāyats of the Vīra-śaivas can hardly be traced in any early work**s, though later Vīra-śaiva writers like Śrīpati and others have twisted some of the older texts which allude to liṅga to mean the specific practices of liṅga-dhāraṇa as done by the Liṅgāyats.

The same chapter says that *liṅga-dhāraṇa* also finds mention in the Basavapurāṇa:

> **According to Basava-purāṇa, the practice of liṅga-dhāraṇa seems to have been in vogue even before Basava.** Basava himself does not say anything about the doctrine of ṣaṭ-sthala, and these two are the indispensably necessary items by which Vīra-śaivism can be sharply distinguished from the other forms of Śaivism, apart from its philosophical peculiarity.

Answer (score 0):

I Found one reference to Linga-Dharana in the Skanda Purana.

> संति रुद्रेण कथिताः शिवधर्मा सनातनाः॥ वीरभद्रो यथा रुद्रस्तथान्ये
> गुरवः स्मृताः॥ ७.३८ ॥ गुरोर्जाताश्च गुरवो विख्याता भुवनत्रये॥ लिंगस्य
> महिमान तु नन्दी जानाति तत्त्वतः॥ ७.३९ ॥ तथा स्कन्दो हि भगवान्न्ये ते
> नामधारकाः॥ यथोक्ताः शिवधरमा हि नन्दिना परिकीर्त्तिताः॥ ७.४० ॥
> **शैलादेन महाभागा विचित्रा लिंगधारकाः॥ शवस्योपरि लिंगं च ध्रियते च पुरातनैः॥ ७.४१ ॥ लिंगेन सह पञ्चत्वं लिंगेन सह जीवितम्॥ एते धर्माः
> सुप्रतिष्ठाः शैलादेन प्रतिष्ठिताः॥ ७.४२ ॥**
>
> There are eternal Śivadharmas mentioned by Rudra where Vīrabhadra,
> Rudra and other Gurus (preceptors) are remembered. The sons of Gurus
> also have become famous in the three worlds as Gurus. Only Nandī knows
> factually the greatness of Liṅga. So also lord Skanda and those others
> who bear his names.
>
> **All the Śivadharmas have been glorified as mentioned by Nandī, the son of Śilāda. Many wonderful persons of exalted nature have been
> glorified as bearers of Liṅgas (Linga Dharakas) .**
>
> Liṅga is held above a dead body by the ancient people.
>
> **Living with Liṅga and dying with Liṅga—these virtuous rites have
> been established by Śailāda (Nandin).**

~ स्कन्दपुराणम्/खण्डः १ (माहेश्वरखण्डः)/केदारखण्डः/अध्यायः ०७

The Text [Lingopanishad](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/lingopaniShat.html) seems to mention it too.

> पञ्चमो **लिङ्गधारणम् । अत्याश्रमाणां मध्ये लिङ्गधारी श्रेष्ठो भवति** ।
> शिरसि महादेवस्तिष्ठतु इति धारयेत् ।

Paramesvaragama Patala 5 seems to mention it too.

[image]